# How to find the mysql data directory from command line in windows

Tags: mysql, database, linux, windows, command-line

In linux I could find the mysql installation directory with the command `which mysql`. But I could not find any in windows. I tried `echo %path%` and it resulted many paths along with path to mysql bin.

I wanted to find the mysql data directory from command line in windows for use in batch program. I would also like to find mysql data directory from linux command line. Is it possible? or how can we do that?

In my case, the mysql data directory is on the installation folder i.e. `..MYSQL\mysql server 5\data` It might be installed on any drive however. I want to get it returned from the command line.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

You can issue the following query from the command line:

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'
```

Output (on Linux):

```
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                      |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr                       |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                    | /tmp                       |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Output (on macOS Sierra):

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                                                     |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/                |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /usr/local/mysql/data/                                    |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                                                           |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                                                        |
| innodb_tmpdir             |                                                           |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/share/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/                              |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/         |
| tmpdir                    | /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/         |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or if you want only the data dir use:

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"'
```

These commands work on Windows too, **but you need to invert the single and double quotes**.

Btw, when executing `which mysql` in Linux as you told, you'll not get the *installation* directory on Linux. You'll only get the binary path, which is `/usr/bin` on Linux, but you see the mysql installation is using multiple folders to store files.

---

If you need the value of datadir as output, and only that, without column headers etc, but you don't have a GNU environment (awk|grep|sed ...) then use the following command line:

```
mysql -s -N -uUSER -p information_schema -e 'SELECT Variable_Value FROM GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"'
```

The command will select the value only from mysql's internal `information_schema` database and disables the tabular output and column headers.

Output on Linux:

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I used mysql -uroot -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir" | grep "datadir" | awk "{print $2}"' for finding actual datadir path in linux. How can find only that path in windows?

Comment: @Prabhu You can do it just with the `mysql` command. No other tools are required. Check my update

Comment: The command executes ok in linux. It does not execute well in windows xp. the first command gives error - you have error in your sql syntax near where Variable_Name = 'dirname'. The second command gives error - unknown database information_schema

Comment: When I try any of these commands in Win7 (AMPPS), I always get a long helpfile displayed, nothing useful. ???

Comment: @hek2mgl, What if I indeed want the path of the executable. What's the equivalent of `which` command in Windows?

Comment: This answer is for Linux only, it doesn't work on Windows 7 64bit, for that OS, login to mysql by `mysql -uuser -p` then enter password and then run query `select @@datadir;` just as As_913 stated.

Comment: The command is intended to work on Windows too. What's the issue?

Comment: To make this work under Windows, just invert the double/single quotes: `mysql -uUSER -p -e "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE '%dir'"`

Comment: Thanks for this! Running "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir""; on my phpmyadmin database helped me find the location of the dabase directory.

Answer (score 183):

You can try this-

```
mysql> select @@datadir;
```

PS- It works on every platform.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: Works on Server 2012 r2

Comment: Works on RHEL 6

Comment: Works on CentOS 7

Comment: Works on Windows

Comment: Works on macos Monterey.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to find datadir in linux or windows you can do following command

`mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"'`

if you are interested to find datadir you can use grep & awk command

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "datadir"' | grep 'datadir' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see the complete list of MySQL server options by running

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

For example, to find out the path to the [data directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) on Linux, you can run:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep ^datadir
```

Example output:

```
datadir                                     /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: interestingly this command gives me `mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` right before the actual `datadir`

I have absolutely no idea why it tries to change working directory. I inspected a bit and it tries that when I use `mysqld --verbose --help`. Probably tries to do some work and needs to go to the data directory

Anyways quick workaround is `mysqld --verbose --help 2>/dev/null | grep ^datadir`

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow command from CLI interface

```
[root@localhost~]# mysqladmin variables -p<password> | grep datadir
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function variables($variable="")
{
  return empty($variable) ? mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES") : mysql_query("SELECT @@$variable");
}

/*get datadir*/
$res = variables("datadir");

/*or get all variables*/
$res = variables();
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the `Data` directory is in `"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data"`. This is where it is on my computer. Someone might find this helpful.