# Where is the Database File stored in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've Installed XAMPP Server, and running localhost for web development Purposes. And Database used is MySQL, In MySQL installation i've created a user named "Rahul" And set a Password for that user.

And this PHP script :https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxeq8o2cryvmps5/Php.php?dl=0
Returns "Database created successfully", So where is the Database file stored Physically on my PC,

How can i Find the Database (.db/.mdb) File, So as to directly View and Upload to a hosting server?

Comment: you can use phpmyadmin in XAMPP to export the database as sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the mysql data directory from command line in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968287/how-to-find-the-mysql-data-directory-from-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: For uploading to server, take a backup/export from phpmyadmin and than import it in server.

Answer (score -1):

**Open phpMyAdmin** and **Click on database** which you want to you want to upload to the server.
then click on **Export** option and then **choose SQL and press go**.
It will create the **.sql** file which contains all the queries which will create exact copy of your database on server.
and if you currently wanted to see which data it contains then export that database in other format such as CSV or wordpad or PDF format...
While you want to upload that database on server just go in phpMyAdmin of server and **import** that .sql file...

Comment: this does not answer the question.